# Batch Script Explanations (For Cycle)

Tags: batch-file

I was working on a Batch script to find a folder in directory, and got it working, thanks to previously found questions on stackoverflow, however, even though it's working as it should, I have few question.

```
for /d /r "%directory%" %%a in (*) do if /i "%%~nxa"=="%foldername%" set "folderpath=%%a"
echo "%folderpath%"
```

What are the **%%a**, **(*)** and **%%-nxa** lines for?

Similarly in this code (searches for a file in directory)

```
for /r "%directory%" %%a in (*) do if "%%~nxa"=="%filename%" set p=%%~dpnxa
```

What does the **%%~dpnxa** do?

As far as the google goes, I was unable to find any explanations, or official MS sites.

Answer (score 4):

excerpt from `for` help :

```
In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been enhanced.
You can now use the following optional syntax:

    %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
    %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
    %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
    %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
    %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
    %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
    %~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
    %~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
    %~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
    %~zI        - expands %I to size of file
    %~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
                   environment variable and expands %I to the
                   fully qualified name of the first one found.
                   If the environment variable name is not
                   defined or the file is not found by the
                   search, then this modifier expands to the
                   empty string
```

`%%a` is the token used in the for loop,`%%~nxa` (on each iteration will correspond to the processed file) is the name and extension of the file. `*` is a wild card which means every symbol.

wildcards- http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html

for loop - http://ss64.com/nt/for.html